# How to use eigen package inside of cmakefiles and c++?

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to use eigen package inside of cmakelists for running c++ Code.

I try to configure

```
set(eigen_package "C:/eigen-3.4.0")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE eigen_package )
```

and it's generating No such file or directory Eigen/Dense

I am using windows OS.
How to configure eigen package

Comment: finally i got the answer

Comment: find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Eigen3::Eigen)